# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, server-error

I am trying to represent whether user has a valid email address in a MVC html document. It seems fairly straight forward, but I keep bumping into the same error.

Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Source Error:

```
 (html document) 

Line 31:     {
Line 32:         <div>
Line 33:             <p>@string.Format(Model.User.FirstName)</p>;
Line 34:         </div>
Line 35:     }
```

In the 'User' model:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the full name.
    /// </summary>
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName);
        }
    }
```

In the model:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user.
    /// </summary>
    public User User { get; set; }
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this might occur?

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Are you sure that your User property is never null?

Comment: The user is set to the current session user, the user wouldn't even be able to log in if it was null.

Comment: well is the first name or last name null?

Comment: I had it working at some stage, then all of a sudden this error popped up, and hasn't gone away!

Comment: well something is null, debug and find out.

Comment: The first name and last name are definitely not null.

Comment: should this line: `@string.Format(Model.User.FirstName)` be `@Html.Raw(Model.User.FullName)`?

Comment: Good spotting, but unfortunately either way the error still appears

Comment: Model is null or User is null or FisrtName one of them is null for sure